# Azure DevOps KeyVault Linked Variable group "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: variableGroupParameters" - how do i fix this?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-cli

I have a need to automate the creation of KeyVault linked variable groups in ADO as part of a pipeline task. I can actually create the var groups after a bit of experimenting. However, using the `az devops invoke` method one is unable to specify the Azure Subscription and this has to be done manually, after the event - however when I do this in the web interface and attempt to save I get the error:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: variableGroupParameters

This means any subsequent editing of the created KeyVault linked var group is pointless as it is unable to save it.

The JSON I am submitting is as follows:

```
  {
    "authorized": true,
    "description": "$description",
    "name": "$name",
    "type": "AzureKeyVault",
    "variableGroupProjectReferences": [{
        "projectReference": {
            "id": "$adoProjectID",
            "name": "$ProjectName"
        },
        "name": "$name",
        "description": "$description"
    }],
    "providerData": {
        "serviceEndpointId": "$AdoSvcConnId",
        "vault": "$KeyVaultNM"
    },

    "variables": {
        "SOMETHINGSECRET": {
            "isSecret": true,
            "value": null,
            "enabled": true,
            "contentType": ""
        },
        "variables": {
            "ANOTHERSECRET": {
                "isSecret": true,
                "value": null,
                "enabled": true,
                "contentType": ""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where the $tokenized values are replaced during the powershell/az cli task

The command (which works but results in broken var group that can't be edited or saved) is as follows:

```
az devops invoke --http-method post --area distributedtask --resource variablegroups --in-file "vgroup_azure_rm.json" --encoding utf-8 --route-parameters project=$ProjectName --api-version 5.0-preview
```

Anyone have an insight in how to fix this please?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? (I am having the same problem)

Comment: No. It isn't fixed. No reply from the az cli team at MS either. I've been told that there is a terraform provider to allow one to do this. Apparently it works written ADO

Comment: There's a reply from them... here:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/using-az-devops-invoke-to-create-keyvaul/1700759?viewtype=all

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem, and the message had nothing to do with the real issue.
I had the following variables:

```json
"variables": {
  "SECRET_1": {
    "contentType": "",
    "isSecret": true,
    "value": "",
    "expires": null,
    "enabled": true
  },
  "SECRET_2": {
    "contentType": "",
    "isSecret": true,
    "value": "",
    "expires": null,
    "enabled": true
  },
  "SECRET_3": {
    "contentType": "",
    "isSecret": true,
    "value": "",
    "expires": null,
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```

And was receiving the same error as you. I removed the expires property and the issue was solved! So my thinking is that the validation checks for any null value and returns the error you are receiving.
Try changing the property value to an empty string ("") instead of null and see whether that solves the problem.

Comment: I am facing the same error, in my case I didn't define the expires property. I only have enabled, isreadonly and issecret options. I don't have any empty values neither. a little bit misleading error in this case :)